# Hidden DTO serialization configuration for model classes when using MemoryPack

Tags: c#, memorypack

In my application I use [MemoryPack](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack) as serializer. I have a quite complex set of datatypes with inheritance where I did use `[MemoryPackUnion]` before. My classes are full with different annotations like `[MemoryPackagable]` and `[MemoryPackInclude]`. All inherit from my interface `ISerializable`.

While it makes sense to have such annotations directly in the data structure you want to configure it does not help to encapsulate the serialization and separate it from the data structures. In my use-case my data-structures need to be serialized with different serializers (MemoryPack and later with one JSON serializer). It would be nice if I can just hide the serialization behind an interface and just throw the structures in and be able to exchange and even compare different serializers:

```
public interface ISerializationService {
  byte[] Serialize(ISerializable serializable);
  ISerializable Deserialize(byte[] data);
}
```

The only idea I currently have is to create wrapper DTOs for each data structure and serializaer which contain the annotations of the corresponding serializer. They serve as an adapter delegating to actual data structure.

This approach would have multiple downsides:

- I need to create a "copy" of each class
- Wrapping each data structure requires more memory and processing time

In particular for MemoryPack, Is there any other way, where I can just stick with a standard behavior for classes and just define the deviations for specific classes or members?